# Magento 2 make guest customer at checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer

At the checkout step the guest is providing all his details including his email, location & phone, what is missing to have an account on the store is just defining the password.

How to get the Guest be a customer within the checkout step?

Comment: Do you need the guest customer to be registered with the site while placing an order?

Comment: Yes I want the guest to be registered during placing an order

Answer (score 0):

You will need a plugin to get the guest data from the order and create a customer

You can use the flowing module:

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-guest-to-customer